# Meaning of imaginary eigenvalues in advection equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, numerical-method

I'm reading the book [Fluid Simulation for Computer Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568813260) (Amazon link), and stumped by the following sentence in Chapter 3:

> what's happening is that the eigenvalues of the Jacobian generated by the central difference are pure imaginary, thus always outside the region of stability.

Could someone explain what is meant here? What's the Jacobian matrix and why are the eigenvalues imaginary? What's the region of stability?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify which part or parts of the sentence are an issue for you? That would help answers address your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the one-dimensional flow of quantity $q(x,t)$. The advection equation is generalized to,
$$
\partial_tq+\partial_xF(q,x)=0\tag{1}
$$
where $F(q,x)$ is the flux of $q$ in the flow--in the case of the advection equation $F(q,x)=qu$. However, we can use the chain rule to write the above as
$$
\partial_tq+\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0
$$
The $\partial_qF$ term is your [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). If $q(x,t)$ is a *set* of values  then $\partial_qF$ is a matrix:
$$
J\equiv\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{\partial F_{q_1}}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial F_{q_1}}{\partial q_2}&\cdots \\\frac{\partial F_{q_2}}{\partial q_1} & \frac{\partial F_{q_2}}{\partial q_2} &\cdots\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{array}\right)
$$
Since this is a matrix, you can find the [eigenvalues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) which can either be real, imaginary, or zero. If the eigenvalues are imaginary, then you have and advection of the form
$$
\partial_tq+iA\partial_xq=0
$$
which does not really make physical sense: how does something flow with a velocity $iA$?

For stability analysis, I am not sure how exactly the Jacobian plays a role (maybe someone else can point it out?), I've only ever seen [von Neumann stability analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) applied to the discretization. For example, consider a one dimensional, constant velocity flow; then Equation (1) is
$$
\partial_tq+u\partial_xq=0
$$
In terms of the central differences, this is
$$
\frac{q_i^{n+1}-q_i^n}{\Delta t}+\frac{u}{2}\frac{q_{i+1}^n-q_{i-1}^n}{\Delta x}=0\tag{2}
$$
where $\Delta t$ is your timestep and $\Delta x$ the width of your cells. If you solve for $q^{n+1}_i$ and assume that
$$
q(x_i,t_n)=G^nq_0e^{ikx_i}
$$
Then (2) becomes (prove this yourself!)
$$
q_i^{n+1}=\sqrt{1+\left(u\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}\sin[k\Delta x]\right)^2}\,q^n_i
$$
For stability, we require that the square-root term (called the *amplification factor*) be less than or equal to 1. In the above, no matter the choice of $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$, it is *always* greater than 1, which means that the growth of $q$ is unconditionally unstable for this central scheme.

Comment: Thank you so much, beautiful answer! Another question is why the author says the advection function only called with a divergence-free velocity? I guess because of the second equation of incompressibility, then how to make the velocity divergence-free?

Comment: Numerically speaking, the divergence-free velocity is more easy to solve, but there is no real requirement that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf u=0$ for the advection equation. Making a velocity divergence free is just finding solutions to $\nabla\cdot\mathbf u=0$ (e.g., $\mathbf u={\rm const}$ is an obvious solution, as is $\mathbf u=y\hat{x}+x\hat{y}$).